# How can I solve this query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have MySQL table name daily_transactions which have five columns namely

```
 id | username | credit | debit | transaction_date
```

If a user credits his account with $100, it will be inserted into the table and if there is a debit (if the user uses our service let say $20), it will also be recorded just like the way bank statement of account history works.

Now the question is, how can I get the list of users that have done a total credit between $500 to $2000 within the last 3months. That is to say sum all credit per user and if it at least $500 to $2000 within the last 3months, show it.

If have tried this query below but it is not working

```
  SELECT username,
         SUM(debit)  
    FROM daily_transactions 
   WHERE sum(credit) >=500 
     AND SUM(credit)<=2000 
     AND DATEDIFF(NOW(),date_details)<=90;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT username,SUM(debit)
FROM daily_transactions
WHERE date_details >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY
GROUP BY username
HAVING SUM(credit) >= 500 AND SUM(credit) <= 2000
```

Note that the filtering on date occurs in the `WHERE` clause.  The filtering on the total occurs *after* the `GROUP BY` in the `HAVING`.

I also changed the date comparison to avoid the function use.  This  allows an index to be used.

Answer (score 1):

`Having`  is a group filter so you need having here

```
   SELECT username,SUM(debit)     
    FROM daily_transactions 
    WHERE  DATEDIFF(NOW(),date_details)<=90;
    group by username
    having sum(credit) >=500 AND SUM(credit)<=2000
```